# How to find a text pattern in text file with python?

Tags: python, file

I need to read a text file and by user interaction, the user enters a pattern for example in this case the user enters **ACA**, the program reads each line of the text file and the output should be:

```
  (2) ACACAC
  (0) TGTGTG
 (15) ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
  (1) TAGACAGTCGATCGACTGCAGCTTCG
```

In this example text file is:

```
  ACACAC
  TGTGTG
  ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
  TAGACAGTCGATCGACTGCAGCTTCG
  CCACCATGGGTGG
```

My code is (but doesn't work correctly):

```
fh = open("sequence.txt", "r")
word = input ("enter your word pattern: ")
s = " "
count = 1
while(s):
    s =fh.readline()
    if word in s :
       print("Line{}".format(count),",", s.count(word) , ":", s, end='')
    count +=1
```

my current output is:

```
Line1, 1 : ACACAC
Line3, 8 : ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
Line4, 1 : TAGACAGTCGATCGACTGCAGCTTCG
```

Comment: You can apply regular expressions here. Example code: `[f"Line{idx}, {len(re.findall('(?=ACA)', line))}, {line}" for idx, line in enumerate(s.splitlines(), 1)]`. [Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Bl3ETP/1).

Comment: @OlvinRoght A lookahead assertion. Nice idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to search for 'word' in the 'line'.
For example you can use re.search to find if there are any matches in a slice of the line, while slicing line with the 'word' length:

```
import re

word = input ("enter your word pattern: ")
with open("sequence.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if re.search(l, line[i:i + len(l)]):
            count += 1
        print(f"({count}) {line}")
```

Comment: what is `l`, why use `re.search` just use `l == line[i:i+len(l)]`